# Aggregating a column by multiple date ranges in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with 5 columns:

```
Device | Name | Date | Source | Income
```

Neither **Device** nor **Name** nor **Source** are unique.

I am trying to write the SQL for getting the following:

```
Device | Name | Source | Income (for last 3 days) | Income (for last 9 days) | Income (for last 12 days)
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a conditional `SUM()` via `CASE` statements:

```
SELECT Device
      ,Name
      ,Source
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 day) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) THEN Income END) AS Last_3_Days
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 9 day) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) THEN Income END) AS Last_9_Days
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Device
        ,Name
        ,Source
```

Comment: Would this be faster than using 3 left joins on the same table?

Comment: @Spartanblogger I suspect the joins would be fractionally faster - but only fractionally, and this is more readable

Comment: I don't see any reason why joins would be faster, they're adding unneeded overhead.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total_l3d FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(Date, NOW()) <= 3
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as total_l9d FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(Date, NOW()) <= 9
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as total_l12d FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(Date, NOW()) <= 12
```